# Make specific parts of resizable image clickable in android app

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an image (imageview) of a giant remote control with many tiny buttons on it. Users want to click a button, but since it's small they zoom in the image so that it's easier to click one. 
I tried implementing it but I could only get it either to be resizable or to have clickable parts. In which ways can this be implemented? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this its used to zoom the image https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: I used PhotoView for zooming the image, but I need to have clickable parts in it that might be moving together with the user resizing/moving the image